# How can I disable a viewController for a time period on iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to disable one of the viewController X(initial View) for a day after the user has pressed a button on viewController X. viewController Y will become initial view during this duration. How can I implement this properly?

Comment: When the user tap on the button, save the current timestamp `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` in `NSUsetDefault`. Check this value everytime you try to present the view controller X. If this is the initial view controller, you have to choose to present either X or Y programmatically in `AppDelegate`. Or have a placeholder view controller as initial view controller and present X or Y conditionally.

Comment: If you only use NSDate you will be relying on the device time. Which can be altered by a user. If you want more security you will want additional checks and synchronization with your server.

Comment: Refer this. http://www.fantageek.com/481/how-to-programmatically-set-initial-view-controller-using-storyboard/.  and dispose your viewController using NSTimer object.  iCamViewController *icvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iCamViewController"];    icvc.Dispose;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in ViewController X you want to use nsuserdefaults to save the date when the button is press like this

```
// Get the current date
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
// Save it in nsuserdefaults using the key myDateKet
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:now forKey:@"myDateKey"];
```

In your AppDelegate.m put this

```
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        // Number of seconds in a day
        double dayInSeconds = 86400; 
        // Get the current date when app opens this gets called
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        // Get the date saved when user pressed the button
        NSDate *savedDate = (NSDate *)[defaults objectForKey:@"myDateKey"];
        // If nil then user has never pressed the button
        if (savedDate == nil) {
             // Therefore view controller x is the root
              self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view controller x"];
        } else {
           // Else user has pressed button so compared the dates
           // One day after the saved date
           NSDate *oneDayAfterSaved = [NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:dayInSeconds sinceDate:savedDate];

           // Compare oneDayAfterSaved to today
           NSComparisonResult result = [today compare:oneDayAfterSaved];
           // Check if the date is the same has one day after the saved date or after then
           if (result == NSOrderedSame || result == NSOrderedDescending) {
               // ViewController x is the root
               self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view controller x"];
           } else {
               // else if before one day after saved date then view controller y
               self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view controller y"];
           }

        }

        return YES;
    }
```